# Could not Reset password using Laravel 5.3.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new to php/laravel tech.
My .env file contains following configuration[1];

When I try to reset the password, It says, password link has been sent, But I haven't received any emails.
What I'm doing wrong here?

p.s: I'm providing null for  MAIL_ENCRYPTION/ MAIL_USERNAME, due to one issue I faced.(Swift_TransportException Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "abc@abc.com" using 2 possible authenticators)

[1]

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=abc@abc.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Administrator"
```

Comment: You've not provided a username or password for mailgun... or you need to change your `MAIL_DRIVER` to `mail` or some other value.

Comment: @fubar  Thanks a lot it works.